# Speed up finding the cell to which a point belongs in interpolation from curvilinear to rectangular grid

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to set up a method for interpolating points from a curvilinear grid to a regular grid.
To do this, I'm trying to find out which cell of the curvilinear grid each point of the regular grid belongs to. The cells of the curvilinear grid are random quadrilaterals.

Grids are created as follows, for example, for an unfavorable case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circle(xn, yn):
    """Polar grid."""
    R = (xn[-1, 0] - xn[0, 0]) / (2*np.pi)
    return (yn + R)*np.sin(xn/R), (yn + R)*np.cos(xn/R)


_x= np.linspace(0, 0.1, 150)
_y = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100)

# Curvilinear grid
up, vp = circle(np.meshgrid(_x, _y, indexing='ij'))

# Cartesian grid
ui = np.linspace(up.min(), up.max(), 300)
vi = np.linspace(vp.min(), vp.max(), 200)
```

I'm able to find the correspondence between each grid using a classic quadrilateral point-finding algorithm:

```
%%cython -f -c=-O2 -I./ --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp

cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef neighbors(double[:, ::1] xp, double[:, ::1] yp, double xi, double yi):
    """Clockwise winding Polygon :

        [[xp[ix, iy], yp[ix, iy]],
         [xp[ix, iy+1], yp[ix, iy+1]],
         [xp[ix+1, iy+1], yp[ix+1, iy+1]],
         [xp[ix+1, iy], yp[ix+1, iy]]])
    """
    cdef Py_ssize_t nx = xp.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t ny = xp.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t ix, iy = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t tag = 0
    cdef double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
    cdef double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4

    for ix in range(nx-1):

        for iy in range(ny-1):

            x1 = xp[ix, iy]
            x2 = xp[ix, iy+1]
            x3 = xp[ix+1, iy+1]
            x4 = xp[ix+1, iy]
            y1 = yp[ix, iy]
            y2 = yp[ix, iy+1]
            y3 = yp[ix+1, iy+1]
            y4 = yp[ix+1, iy]

            if xi - min(x1, x2, x3, x4) < 0.:
                continue

            if yi - min(y1, y2, y3, y4) < 0.:
                continue
            
            # Check that point (xi, yi) is on the same side of each edge of the quadrilateral
            if not (xi - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (x2 - x1) * (yi - y1) > 0:
                continue
            if not (xi - x2) * (y3 - y2) - (x3 - x2) * (yi - y2) > 0:
                continue
            if not (xi - x3) * (y4 - y3) - (x4 - x3) * (yi - y3) > 0 :
                continue
            if not (xi - x4) * (y1 - y4) - (x1 - x4) * (yi - y4) > 0:
                continue

            tag = 1
            break
        if tag == 1:
            break
    if tag == 1:
        return (ix, iy), (ix, iy+1), (ix+1, iy+1), (ix+1, iy)
    return None
```

And it works:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

for i in np.arange(0, ui.shape[0]):
    axes.axvline(ui[i], color='k', linewidth=0.1)
for i in np.arange(0, vi.shape[0]):
    axes.axhline(vi[i], color='k', linewidth=0.1)

for i in np.arange(0, vp.shape[1]):
    axes.plot(up[:, i], vp[:, i], 'k', linewidth=0.5)
for i in np.arange(0, up.shape[0]):
    axes.plot(up[i, :], vp[i, :], 'k', linewidth=0.5)

for iu, iv in ((180, 120), (100, 90), (80, 40), (10, 10)):
    axes.plot(ui[iu], vi[iv], 'ro')
    idx = neighbors(up, vp, ui[iu], vi[iv])
    if idx:
        for _idx in idx:
            axes.plot(up[_idx], vp[_idx], 'go')
plt.show()
```

The thing is, on my system, each point search takes an average of 15 us for this grid (7 ms for a 2000x2000 grid), i.e. for the search of 2000x2000 points, an estimated time of 28000 seconds (not to mention the 3d case :)).

I think I can save time by avoiding the search for points that don't exist in the curvilinear grid, but I can't find a simple indicator to skip the search for these points.

I think there's a better global method for this kind of research, but I'm not aware of it.

How could I speed up the things using Cython/numpy?

By using a simple dichotomy to target the x's, it is possible to save quite a lot of calculation time. On the other hand, the code presented below can lead to errors if x is not monotonic:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef bint is_monotonic(double[:, ::1] v):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i

    for i in range(v.shape[0] - 1):
        if (v[i, 1] > v[i, 0]) != (v[i+1, 1] > v[i+1, 0]):
            return False
    return True


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef (double, double) minmax(double[:] arr):
    cdef double min = arr[0]
    cdef double max = arr[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t n = arr.shape[0]

    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] < min:
            min = arr[i]
        elif arr[i] > max:
            max = arr[i]
    return min, max


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef (Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t) dichotomy(double[:, ::1] xp, double xi, Py_ssize_t offset=1):

    cdef Py_ssize_t nx = xp.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t istart = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t istop = nx - 1
    cdef Py_ssize_t middle = (istart + istop) // 2
    cdef double xmin1, xmin2, xmax1, xmax2
    cdef double xmin, xmax


    while (istop - istart) > 3:

        middle = (istart + istop) // 2

        xmin1, xmax1 = minmax(xp[istart, :])
        xmin2, xmax2 = minmax(xp[middle, :])
        xmin = min(xmin1, xmax1, xmin2, xmax2)
        xmax = max(xmin1, xmax1, xmin2, xmax2)

        if xmin <= xi <= xmax:
            if middle - istart < 3:
                return istart - offset, middle + offset
            istop = middle
        else:
            istart = middle

    xmin1, xmax1 = minmax(xp[middle, :])
    xmin2, xmax2 = minmax(xp[istop, :])
    xmin = min(xmin1, xmax1, xmin2, xmax2)
    xmax = max(xmin1, xmax1, xmin2, xmax2)

    if xmin <= xi <= xmax:
        return middle - offset, istop + offset
    return -1, -1

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef neighbor(double[:, ::1] xp, double[:, ::1] yp, double xi, double yi):

    (...)

    cdef Py_ssize_t istart = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t istop = nx - 2

    if is_monotonic(xp):
        istart, istop = dichotomy(xp, xi)
        if istart == -1:
            return None

    for ix in range(istart, istop + 1):
        for iy in range(ny-1):
            (...)
```

Comment: I wonder if some other math or computation board would be better for this.  My guess is that you've gotten as much speed possible with this algorithm.  I know from work years ago that it's a lot easier to convert grid points and 'local' coordinates into global coordinates, than it is go the other way.